# Child component is not being called inside subscribe method in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe, angular-changedetection

I need to call a method showError() which opens a modal pop up by sending toggle : 'open' to the overlay component.

parent component html:

```
<c-overlay [overlay]="contentErrorOverlay">
  <h3>{{contentErrorOverlay.message}}</h3>
</c-overlay>
```

parent component ts:

```
 methodWhichCallsOnFocusoutOfMyFormField() {
            //this.showError('msg'); -> If I call here, the pop up works properly.
    this.service.method(input).subscribe(res => {
        this.showError('msg'); // -> But If I call here, the showError() is getting called completely; but the pop up doesnt show up, and the constructor in overlay component doesnt hit at all
    })


 public showError(msg) {
    this.contentErrorOverlay = {
      toggle: 'open',
      message: msg
    };
  }
```

I tried Appref.tick() and ngZone thinking that it might be a change detection issue since it is called when focus out but it did not help.

Any suggestion or answer would be very helpful.

Comment: What kind of service are you using? Have you tried `ngZone.run` or `cdRef.detectChanges()`?

Comment: @yurzui yes, the service is just to get the form values are correct or not. If the service returns validation fails message, that needs to be showed in the modal popup by calling showError(). I tried both ngZone.run and cdRef, but it didnt help

Comment: It would be great if you could reproduce it in stackblitz

Comment: @yurzui   changeDetectorRef.markForCheck(); did the job!! thanks  a lot :D